# How can I use command in sed replace with groups capturing?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file like this in content :
`#INCLUDE<~/boulou/billy.txt>`

And from a bash/sed script/command, I want to replace this line by the content of the file `~/boulou/billy.txt`

This is my current command that can find the file path :

```
sed -E "s/#INCLUDE\<(.*)\>/\1/g" test.sh
```

This shows me the file path but when I want to fetch the content with this :

```
sed -E "s/#INCLUDE\<(.*)\>/$(cat \1)/g" test.sh
```

I get the error "cat: 1: No such file or directory"

Let me know if you want more information.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Hmm, i want to have the content of the file (e.g. ~/boulou/billy.txt) in replacement of the whole line (#INCLUDE<~/boulou/billy.txt>)

Comment: @ChristopheCoquelet That's not an example, that's literally just what your question says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because it first runs `cat \1` (which is the same as `cat 1`), inserts the output into the sed command, then runs `sed -E "s/...//g" test.sh` (empty replacement because `cat 1` outputs nothing on stdout).

This is because the shell processes `$( ... )` first, then runs the resulting command line.

For what you're trying to do, you have to read the file from inside the search/replace command, not up front.

I don't know how to do that with sed, so I'd simply use Perl:

```
perl -pe 's{#INCLUDE<([^<>]*)>}{ open my $fh, "<", $1 or die "$1: $!"; local $/; readline $fh }eg' test.sh
```

However, this will not work with your example because `~/boulou/billy.txt` does not exist (you most likely do not have a directory literally called `~` in your current working directory). To fix this (and simplify the code considerably), I'd use:

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -pe 's{#INCLUDE<([^<>]*)>}{ path($1)->slurp }eg' test.sh
```

However, this requires the [`Path::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module, which is not part of the core perl distribution.

It's possible to expand `~` manually, but that makes the code even messier (this is the point at which I'd consider putting it in a separate script file):

```
perl -pe 's{#INCLUDE<([^<>]*)>}{ my $p = $1; $p =~ s{^~/}{$ENV{HOME}/}; open my $fh, "<", $p or die "$p: $!"; local $/; readline $fh }eg' test.sh
```

(Disclaimer: Somewhat hacky, does not handle `~user` notation, only replaces a leading `~/` by the contents of the `HOME` environment variable.)

Comment: I would say that melpomene's answer is better than mine.  It actually has a solution whereas I just pointed you to awk and m4.  I would say that perl is way more useful than awk.  If you had to invest time in another language, I would go with perl.  Consider perl a superset of awk ( it has an 'awk mode').

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your explaination ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that :

```
$ sed -r 's/#INCLUDE<(.*)>/printf "%b" "$(cat \1)"/e' test.sh
```

It should work pretty smooth :)

Comment: The `e` flag seems to be a GNU extension, so this requires GNU sed.

Comment: Simple, i like that ! :D

Comment: Indeed, the e flag is only available in GNU sed... not BSD sed. Meh

Comment: That's completely wrong, didn't anyone test it? That'll strip all the white space and newlines from the file being included and it'll, potentially disastrously, try to execute the whole of the line in test.sh that includes the INCLUDE statement.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^#INCLUDE<\(.*\)>$/cat \1/e' file
```

This evaluates the expression on the right side of the substitution command. In this case it will replace the matched line by the contents of the file named between `<` and `>`.

Comment: Much closer to correct than the currently accepted answer and should be fine as long as the INCLUDE is on it's own line and the file name to be included only contains alphanumeric characters (e.g. not spaces or `;` or anything else that executing the shell would interpret when executing the replacement text). `cat '\''\1'\''` would be more robust or `cat "\1"` if the OP wants shell variables in the file path to be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the shell is replacing $(cat \1) way early.  That is, even before the sed command is executed and passed that parameters, the shell is doing the interpolation.

If you are just doing #INCLUDE substitutions, you may consider using m4.   Awk may be a reasonable way of approaching this if you need to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

This will work robustly with any input file contents running any awk in any shell on any UNIX system:

**INPUT:**

```
$ cat file1
before
foo [#INCLUDE<file2>] bar
after

$ cat file2
stuff
&       nonsense
    here
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/#INCLUDE<[^<>]*>/) {
    file = substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-10)
    rep = sep = ""
    while ( (getline line < file) > 0 ) {
        rep = rep sep line
        sep = ORS
    }
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) rep substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
{ print }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1
before
foo [stuff
&       nonsense
    here] bar
after
```

Here's what [the currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51459473/1745001) will do with that same input:

```
$ sed -r 's/#INCLUDE<(.*)>/printf "%s" $(cat \1)/e' file1
before
/bin/sh: foo: command not found

after
```

and here's what it'll do if the INCLUDE is on a line of it's own:

```
$ cat file1
before
#INCLUDE<file2>
after

$ sed -r 's/#INCLUDE<(.*)>/printf "%s" $(cat \1)/e' file1
before
stuff&nonsensehere
after
```

This simpler script would be closer to correct if INCLUDE was on a line of its own:

```
$ sed -r 's/#INCLUDE<(.*)>/cat \1/e' file1
before
stuff
&       nonsense
    here
after
```

but would also fail if any other text was on the line as it'd still try to execute it!